# xpath: element have not specific parent between final

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I try to select all elements which has attribute name `itemprop` and whith has any level  parent with attribute `itemtype = http://schema.org/Product` except elements which located into nodes with  any other  attribute `itemtype`.

Example:

```
<div itemtype = "http://schema.org/Product" >
  <div itemtype = "http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList" >
    <div itemprop = "name" > A </div>
    <div itemprop = "price" > B </div>
    <div itemtype = "http://schema.org/ListItem" >
      <div itemprop = "description"> C </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div itemprop = "name" > D </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div itemprop = "price" > E </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need only D and E elements but not A, B, C.
I tried somerhing like this:

```
//*[normalize-space(@itemtype) = 'http://schema.org/Product']/descendant::*[not(descendant-or-self::*[@itemtype])][@itemprop]
```

This string not valid at all and other my attempts did not exclude A, B and C elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use below expression which allow to get elements with ancestors that have attribute `itemtype` with `"http://schema.org/Product"` value only

```
//div[@itemprop and count(ancestor::*[@itemtype='http://schema.org/Product'])=count(ancestor::*[@itemtype])]
```

Comment: it's great. You helped me. Thanks very much!